# How to fix an external HDD with Windows 7 partition to show up in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, partition-recovery, raw

I have an HDD I removed from an old Toshiba laptop that I had way back which had a problem with its power jack. I managed to switch the HDD with another external HDD's docking station. I gave the laptop to a cousin of mine and when I was at his place, his Windows 7 laptop was able to read the HDD without problems.

However, when I connect it to my Windows 10 laptop, it shows up as an unformatted drive with 0 bytes. In Disk Management, it comes up as RAW. There's absolutely nothing wrong with the drive. It's just that Windows 10 can't read it.

I used [MiniTool](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/) to browse the HDD and sure enough it was able to list the partition and files. The scary part is that MiniTool was able to read files that I had long deleted before entirely formatting the drive and installing a new OS. :/

So, is there a way to make Windows 10 to be able to read the disk without having to backup/restore? Thanks.

[image: HDD exhibit]

Comment: What format is the hard disk in? Windows 10 has no issues reading most older file systems, unless they are really ancient. Is it encrypted?

Comment: NTFS with MBR. A standard Windows 7 installation. I'll try connecting it to a Win7 VirtualBox or if I can find a laptop laying by soon enough I can try to boot from it and see what happens

Comment: I tried booting from the drive through USB and it got into a loop and eventually the BIOS loader gave up and said there were no bootable drives.